# How to create a new JSON object in every loop iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a feature that given my daily work hours and the start and end date of my contract displays in a calendar my work hours. The problem is when I have 2 or more shifts on the same day. Let's say Julian has a shift from 03:00 to 04:00 and another one on the same day from 5:00 to 6:00 every Monday starting from July 17, 2019 to July 31, 2019. That means that my calendar should display these 2 shifts in July 22 and July 29. I have coded the logic to get me the correct dates. As of right now my JSON response looks like this

{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-22","day":"Monday","start_time":["03:00","05:00"],"end_time":["04:00","06:00"]},{"user_":"Julian","start":"2019-07-29","day":"Monday","start_time":["03:00","05:00"],"end_time":["04:00","06:00"]}

which is being generated by the following code in my JSON builder file

```rb
        json.array! event.each do |inevent|

              json.id hr_schedule.id
              json.user_id hr_schedule.user_id

              json.start inevent.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
              day_of_week = inevent.strftime('%A') 
              json.day day_of_week
              if day_of_week == "Monday"
                  json.start_time hr_schedule.monday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.monday_end  
              elsif day_of_week == "Tuesday"
                  json.start_time hr_schedule.tuesday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.tuesday_end               
              elsif day_of_week == "Wednesday"
                  json.start_time hr_schedule.wednesday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.wednesday_end   
              elsif day_of_week == "Thursday"

                  json.start_time hr_schedule.thursday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.thursday_end    
              elsif day_of_week == "Friday"

                  json.start_time hr_schedule.friday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.friday_end  

              elsif day_of_week == "Saturday"
                  json.start_time hr_schedule.saturday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.saturday_end    
              elsif day_of_week == "Sunday" 
                  json.start_time hr_schedule.sunday_st
                  json.end_time hr_schedule.sunday_end  
              end



     end
```

what I want to achieve is to be able to have all my events as a unique JSON object  like the following

{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-22","day":"Monday","start_time":"03:00","end_time":"04:00"},{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-22","day":"Monday","start_time":"05:00","end_time":"06:00"},
{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-29","day":"Monday","start_time":"03:00","end_time":"04:00"},{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-29","day":"Monday","start_time":"05:00","end_time":"06:00"}

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it was a typo, I updated the description it should have been  a shift from 03:00 to 04:00 and another one on the same day from 5:00 to 6:00

Comment: What class is `json`? I'm not familiar with the `array!` method.

Comment: @muistooshort: in this case, the do/end block will bind to `json.array!`, I think.

Comment: Try not to use English words as keys or drivers for your logic. Numbers or explicitly machine readable codes are almost always better. This won't work on someone's computer if they set their language to anything other than English, and not every developer will have English set as their default.

Comment: You're setting `json.user_id hr_schedule.user_id` but you're getting `"user":"Julian"` and also `"user_":"Julian"` (note the underscore). How are `user` and `user_` getting set? And where is `id`? Are you sure this is the code which is generating that JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what class `json` is, nor what `array!` is doing. But the basic way to do what you want is to use `map` to turn your events into an Array of Hashes. Then turn the Array into JSON with `to_json`.

```
calendar = event.map do |inevent|
  json = {}

  json[:id] = hr_schedule.id
  json[:user] = hr_schedule.user_id

  json[:start] = inevent.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
  json[:day] = inevent.strftime('%A')

  case inevent.wday
  when 0
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.sunday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.sunday_end  
  when 1
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.monday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.monday_end  
  when 2
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.tuesday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.tuesday_end               
  when 3
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.wednesday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.wednesday_end   
  when 4
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.thursday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.thursday_end    
  when 5
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.friday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.friday_end  
  when 6
    json[:start_time] = hr_schedule.saturday_st
    json[:end_time] = hr_schedule.saturday_end    
  end

  json
end

puts calendar.to_json
```

I've simplified it a bit by using a [case/when](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/) and [Time#wday](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-wday). `strftime(%A)` might change if the language of the application changes, and the day of week numbers are harder to typo.

---

As a side note, this event structure limits itself to only events which end before midnight. Consider instead using a full ISO8061 datetimes for start and end. In general, it's easier to work with a full datetime than separate date and time. The event day can be inferred from `start`.

```
{"user":"Julian","start":"2019-07-22T03:00","end":"2019-07-22T04:00"}
```

Or if the events are relative, like they happen every Monday, consider a start and a [duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). And use an [ISO weekday number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for the day instead of a string, less parsing for the receiver to do.

```
{"user":"Julian","day":1,"start":"03:00","duration":"P1H"}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure what class json is" - it's [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) DSL

Comment: Consider `calendar = event.flat_map do |inevent|; [:start, :end].map do |when|; json = {};...`, after having defined `labels = { start: 'start_time', end: 'end_time' }` and `appropriate_variable_name_that_does_not_come_to_mind = { start: [hr_schedule.sunday_st, hr_schedule.monday_st,..], end: hr_sunday_end, hr_monday_end,...] }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You really like your data mappings. :) That approach means you call every `X_st` and `X_end` method every iteration of the loop, a waste of time. Instead you'd store the methods `[:sunday_st, :monday_st, ...]` and use `send`. That introduces too much complexity for this answer. In this case the root problem is how `hr_schedule` is structured. Rather than storing start/end times for each day in one object, it should be storing a row per day of the week with the day of week, start time, and duration. Then `schedule_for_day = hr_schedule.for_day(dow)`.

Comment: Could scrunch this down even more if you had a lookup table to convert numbers to days, then `hr_schedule.send("#{day}_st")` and so on.

Comment: Those methods (`X_st` and `X_end`) don't have arguments, so they are called but once, when the hash `approp...` is constructed. As it replaces the case statement with a loop over `wday`'s of the week I'd argue it reduces complexity and increases the chance of cut-and-paste and then forgetting-to-edit errors.

Comment: @Schwern thanks your answer guided me on the right track